# What is ms-hcTest?

Tags: 2013, master-page

Between the Suite Bar (`<div id="suiteBar">`) and the Ribbon Row (`<div id="s4-ribbonrow">`) there is a content-less div with id of ms-hcTest (`<div id="ms-hcTest"/>`).

Does anyone know what the purpose of this div is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Init.Js` there is a function called `AllowCSSFiltersOnIE8()`.

It checks for IE version and if it is Ie8 or below. Adds `ms-core-needIEFilter` css class to body tag, then checks for border style on `ms-hcTest`, and if it is not applied, removes css filter for `s4-workspace`.

So this element is just for checking whether there is a need to use filters or not. And it's only for IE8 and below.

Comment: You, sir, take the cake. I asked this over 6 months ago!